# Failed to compile React Hook "useQuery" is called in function "home" which is neither a React function component or a custom React Hook function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, graphql, react-hooks, apollo

My react app is showing the below error in browser

```
Failed to compile
./src/pages/home.js
  Line 24:30:  React Hook "useQuery" is called in function "home" which is neither a React function component or a custom React Hook function  react-hooks/rules-of-hooks
```

Comment: ... and relevant home.js fragment ...?

Comment: Chances are that you forgot to type your component with something like `: React.FC` so that the compiler knows it is a React component. Otherwise, as the message says, `useQuery` can only be used inside a React function component (not a class component).

Answer (score 1):

I saw the below warning

```
Warning: The tag <home> is unrecognized in this browser. If you meant to render a React component, start its name with an uppercase letter.
```

and changed the `<home/>` to `<Home/>`

This fixed the issue!

PS: All React component names must start with a capital letter. If you start a component name with a lowercase letter, it will be treated like a built-in element like a  or a  . This is because of the way JSX works.